# rubocop fail level and failing build

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubocop

I have set up Rubocop in my CI Bamboo build, however since there are offenses detected it has an Exit status of 1 which fails this task.

Since I am generating a Rubocop HTML report in the ci task I want the task to pass.

How can I stop rubocop from failing the task, is it something to do with:

```
--fail-level
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the end:

```
'--fail-level F'
```

worked as a rubocop flag, so it will only fail if there are fatal errors.  The docs are not clear on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ignore rubocop exit code and continue your CI pipeline you should `|| true`.

So if you are running rubocop like this:

```
$ rubocop
```

Then change it to:

```
$ rubocop || true
```

which will return exit code 0 and won't stop your pipeline.

Comment: Failing task since return code of [bin/bundle exec rubocop app -f html || true] was 1 while expected 0

Comment: could you share this part of your Bamboo pipeline?

Comment: Is it a `command task` or `script task`? For this to work it should be a `script task`. otherwise it will only respect the exit code of the first command.

Comment: I'm using the bamboozled Bundler CLI plugin in bamboo

Answer (score 0):

I've added this spec to my CI to check Syntax only.

```
require 'spec_helper'

RSpec.describe 'rubocop analysis' do
  subject(:report) { `rubocop --only Lint/Syntax` }

  it 'has no offenses' do
    expect(report).to match(/no\ offenses\ detected/)
  end
end
```